# Focus Div after button Click

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<input type="button" onclick="$('#c')[0].focus()" value="test focus"/>
<div>
    <div id="c" tabindex="1" style="margin-top:800px;">testing</div>
</div>
```

Why this Html Code won't Work  . what i want is after the click it will direct to focus div. Thank in advance :)

Comment: It does work, you might however confuse focus for skipping to anchor?

Comment: its working, you might confused, whats extra functionality you want? smooth scrolling?

Comment: what i Want is if i click it will direct me to buttom scroll.. The thing that happen to me is even i clicked the button already its not scrolling down..

Comment: Thanks for giving me Idead guys... thank thank you smooth scrolling .. is what i wanted :D thanks thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works as it is expected. When you click button, your div is in focus.

```css
#c:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="$('#c')[0].focus()" value="test focus" />
<div>
  <div id="c" tabindex="1" style="margin-top:300px;">testing</div>
</div>
```

On button click, `testing` div has border.

Comment: Thank you... guys .. hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mybutton").click(function(){

    // focus and select

   $('#c').focus().select();

})
})
</script>
```

// Give id to button

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="test focus" />
<div>
  <div id="c" tabindex="1" style="margin-top:300px;">testing</div>
</div>
```